# How to search/filter item in pagination android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, pagedlist

I have a paginated recycler view from room database using MVP and RXjava .Each item is checked or unchecked, and modified to main PagedList. Now I want to search from this list. How can I do it? I can't query from database as I have not stored the recent value.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZOZ0.png)

I want to search from pagedList.

```
public class AttendanceAdapter extends PagedListAdapter<ChildAttendance,AttendanceAdapter.ViewHolder>  {


    HashMap<String,ChildAttendance> presentHashmap;

    public AttendanceAdapter(AttendanceAdapter.OnItemCheckListenerdiffCallback) {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
        this.presentHashmap=new HashMap<>();

    }

    public HashMap<String, ChildAttendance> getPresentHashmap() {
        return presentHashmap;
    }




    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         ChildAttendance child = getChildAttendance(position);


             holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                ...changes to list
               c.changeState()

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: so what would be your search criteria? you want to search only within those items that are "checked" with some `CheckBox` / `Switch`?

Comment: @pskink i want to search  fields such as name, phone number, etc.. from List<ChildAttendance>

Comment: @psking Item is initialially checked or unchecked from database. Then user click or unclicks it. I have posted picture with the question.https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZOZ0.png

Comment: means "checked state" is saved in database. I only want to search items (ChildAttendance list ).